# Is it possible to dynamically generate Unicode characters in Java?

Tags: java, string, unicode

Basically, I would like to use Unicode symbols in my `System.out.println` lines, but these Unicode characters would need to be dynamically generated.

For example, take symbols `U+2074`, `U+2075` and `U+2076`, which return, respectively, `x^4`, `x^5` and `x^6`. To print them in Java I would use `\u2074`, `\u2075` and `\u2076`, but what if I want to generate them based on another value (i.e. `\u207x` where `x` is a variable)?

If I were using PHP, i would use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for this which would be extremely handy.

I even went as far as thinking about using a hack like saving `u207` as a String, making my calculations on the value of `x` and appending this value to the string, but then there are issues introducing the `\` symbol inside a string:

```
String unicodeBase = "u207";
// I do something to get a value for x
String unicodeChar = "u207" + x;
System.out.println("\unicodeChar");
```

If i do this, I get an `illegal unicode escape` error, which is expected. But then, if I escape the `\` symbol, then the output is a string that is not processed:

```
System.out.println("\\unicodeChar");
```

This returns the string `unicodeChar`.

So, is it possible to dynamically generate Unicode characters in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast the codepoint value to a `char`:

```
(char)0x2070 + x
```

Note that you probably think about codepoint values in hex.

Comment: Interesting, at least this is not erroring out :) If I do that, however, I simply get a superscript `0` and nothing more.

Comment: Then you have the wrong codepoint.